# Makefile for C++/MATLAB Engine API

Tags: c++, matlab, makefile, linker, matlab-engine

If I understand properly the idea behind the API is to be able to pass some data back and forth from C++ and MATLAB (provided the MATLAB environment is up and running on the computer) to get the best of both worlds.

Concretely what I am trying to do is to use the API in a simulation code as to not have to open MATLAB manually every time I want to get plots from my C++ program. I understand there are other options such as compiling directly using mex in MATLAB (which I haven't been able to do because as I execute the compiled file it cannot load the shared libraries properly)...

For starters, I have been trying to execute the example (engdemo.cpp) provided by MATLAB.

I tried updating my makefile to include the libraries and references to the necessary header files:

> MATLABROOT = /.../matlab/**r2012b**
>
> CFLAGS = -I${MATLABROOT}/extern
>
> LIBS = -L${MATLABROOT}/bin/glnxa64
>
> Then g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -leng -lmx demo.cpp -o demo

But I get a bunch of warnings about libeng and libmx not being able to find other *.so files.

When I manually checked the folder containing the *.so (namely .../bin/glnxa64) I've realized they were not called -leng and -lmx but libeng and libmx.

**1) So first of all I would like to know why I have to call them in a different way?**

The warning messages advised me to use the *-rpath* or *-rpath-link* option which I guessed was some kind of recursion, which I don't understand because all the *.so are in the same folder. I still tried and it didn't work because the option would not be recognized. I therefore tried to manually request the execution of the other *.so and it worked for some of them but not all and I still didn't understand at that point why should they be called as -l*** insted of -lib***.

**2) So my second question is, what can I do to solve this issue or is there an easy way to run this example?**

Here's a screenshot of the terminal output:
[image: Terminal output, missing link in references]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was a matter of versioning in both cases. I reinstalled and (almost) everything worked.